# Python append to ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an `np.ndarray`:

```
[[0 4 0 0] [0 5 8 2] [2 7 3 2]]
```

I want to append in position 0 another element so that the output looks like:

```
[['cat' 0 4 0 0] ['cat' 0 5 8 2] ['cat' 2 7 3 2]]
```

I've tried `np.insert, append, vstack`, and `concatenate` as indicated in other posts. But, none work. I suspect this is because the type of my array is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. I've also tried converting it to a list and appending it or to a normal `np.array`, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Edit:

I tried:

```
    arr=[np.append('cat',i) for i in my_array]
```

This works, however, the output looks like:

```
[array(['cat' 0 4 0 0], dtype=object), array(['cat' 0 5 8 2], dtype=object), array(['cat' 2 7 3 2], dtype=object)]
```

Comment: numpy arrays like being one datatype.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh but even adding an int doesn't work...

Comment: and why should it? your example is trying to add "cat". thats not an int, and cant be typecast to one.

Comment: Why didn't it work with listsl? Have you tried `[['cat'] + i for i in l]`

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I understand that cat is a string.. I was just telling you that I had tried inserting an int too

Comment: i see. inserting ints should work just fine.

Comment: @yatu I get this error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: You need to pay more attention to the array's `dtype`.  The original looks like it has an `int` `dtype`.  You can't add a string to that and still get a `int` array.  If you started with a string dtype it should work.  There's an `object` dtype, and compound dtypes, but I'm not sure you understand `numpy` enough yet to use those profitably.

Comment: To continue @hpaulj's comment, an ndarray has all the same dtypes (float or int or string). You need a record array or structured array if you want to mix types (ints and strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ndarray` is a container for *homogenous* data; that is, every element must be of the same type.

To accomplish what you're trying to do with the correct type, it's as simple as using [`insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html#numpy-insert). In this example, I insert `-1` at index `0` along the column axis:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 5, 8, 2],
       [2, 7, 3, 2]])
>>> np.insert(a, 0, -1, axis=1)
array([[-1,  0,  4,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  5,  8,  2],
       [-1,  2,  7,  3,  2]])
```

Comment: @user3755632 it may give the correct output but "works" is loose here; it a) completely trashes any hope of getting any benefit of numpy beyond advanced indexing (no vectorized operations will work), and b) is extremely inefficient if done more than a couple of times because shape changes force a full copy of the entire array - lists are generally faster.

Comment: @roganjosh Should I delete this answer? I'm not sure I fully understand your "a)" point.

Comment: Absolutely not what I'm suggesting, sorry. It's more a note to the OP that, while this gives them their desired output, it is not really in-line with what numpy is for. They might want to review the overall approach.

Comment: Numpy can drop calculations straight down into C and use vectorization; this can make certain calculations orders of magnitude faster. While your example is totally numerical, I got the impression (perhaps incorrectly) that the OP wants arrays of mixed type, and vectorization will then become impossible

Comment: :) My comment should have been worded much more clearly, I didn't mean to imply the answer was technically incorrect, apologies.

Comment: @user3755632, curious how you got it to work by adding a string. I get an error if I replace `np.insert` above with `np.insert(a, 0, 'cat', axis=1)` (erro message: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'cat')